# display an image from file in wpf isn't working?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button b3 and an image named pictureBox1 . Im using WPF, however I'm using the winforms openFileDialog instead of the one that comes with WPF :

below is the code that I put inside the click event of my button :

```
 private void b3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openDialogIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        if (openDialogIcon.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
            Image i = new Image();
            BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
            src.BeginInit();
            src.UriSource = new Uri(openDialogIcon.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
            src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            src.EndInit();
            i.Source = src;
            i.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            //int q = src.PixelHeight;        // Image loads here

        }
    }
```

When I click the button and select an icon. The icon doesn't appear in the pictureBox1.

Can someone please explain why the code above doesn't show the icon inside the pictureBox?

Comment: I can't see where you assign something to pictureBox1...

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Sorry I had to look into the code a bit more before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your image to the pictureBox, else you wont see it on your screen and you only made the image object in memory.

```
private void b3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openDialogIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    if (openDialogIcon.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.UriSource = new Uri(openDialogIcon.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
        src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        src.EndInit();
        pictureBox1.Source = src;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to drag and drop a `Image` control in your window

```
...
//imageStretch <- the name of Image control
 i.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
 //int q = src.PixelHeight;        // Image loads here
 imageStretch.Source = src;

...
```